# Rotate value text vertically outside bar in BarChart MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

Rotate value text vertically outside bar in `BarChart` `MPAndroidChart`

I am able to rotate the text but it is coming inside the bar which I have achieved using code below:

`chart.setRenderer(CustomBarChartRenderer(context, this, this.getAnimator(), this.getViewPortHandler()))`

```
public class CustomBarChartRenderer extends BarChartRenderer {
      public CustomBarChartRenderer(BarDataProvider chart, 
                                    ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
           super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
      }

      @Override
      public void drawValue(Canvas canvas, IValueFormatter formatter, 
                            float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, float x, float y, int color) {
           mValuePaint.setColor(color);

           canvas.save();
           canvas.rotate(-90);

           canvas.drawText(formatter.getFormattedValue(value, entry, 
                                                       dataSetIndex, mViewPortHandler), x, y, mValuePaint);
           canvas.restore();
      }
}
```

Text is rotated but comes inside the bar can see in the image link below:

[image]

How to make text value properly align above the bar??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by moving the label up.

Worth noticing is x and y dimensions changes internally as we are rotating the label so for moving label up you have to increase x value and not y value.

Also note to make it dynamic and work for all text lengths, I am calculating the pixel size for text to be displayed and moving label up by that pixel size only. See code below (in kotlin):

```
override fun drawValue(c: Canvas, formatter: IValueFormatter, value: Float, entry: Entry, dataSetIndex: Int, x: Float, y: Float, color: Int) {
    mValuePaint.color = Color.WHITE
    val text = formatter.getFormattedValue(value, entry, dataSetIndex, mViewPortHandler)

    c.save()
    val width = mValuePaint.measureText(text)
    c.rotate(-90f, x, y)

    c.drawText(text, x + (width / 2), y, mValuePaint)
    c.restore()
}
```